# Can Hibernate select a join table without including some rows

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I use Hibernate to control my database and I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User`(
    `id`        INT             NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`      VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `account`       VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    `password`      VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL    DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Project` (
    `id`        INT             NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `manager`   INT             NOT NULL,   
    `name`      VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL    DEFAULT '', 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`manager`) REFERENCES `User`(`id`)
)
```

And I have done the mapping:

*User:*

```
// ... import code
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name, account, password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
    private List<Project> projects;

    public User() {
    }
    //  ... Getter & Setter code
}
```

*Project:*

```
// ... import code
@Entity
@Table
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager")
    private User manager;

    public Project () {
    }
    //  ... Getter & Setter code
}
```

I want to know whether it is possible when I select projects, the project will include its manager data but not have password.

In other ways, I want that each project I get will like this (format as JSON):

```json
{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "A test project",
    "manager": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "John Smith"
        "accound": "user1",
        "password": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Projection

A [projection](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-projection) could be used to limit the fields you want to bring into memory, you could get a projection of all fields except the `password`.

## 2. Lazy

Another option can be adding the lazy annotation to the field:

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Column(...)
private String password;
```

## 3. HQL query

Another way would be to use a direct HQL query and load only the required fields, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25970439/691916).

Comment: **1.** Sorry, I cannot find any method can let me ignore _password_ in Projection
**2.** I tried `FetchType.LAZY` but it still display password
**3.** If the code is like `session.createQuery("Select new Project(id, name) from Project")`, it can works. However, I haver no idea how it become something like `"Select new Project(id, name, creatorName) from Project"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to map this field at all, you could use `@Transient` annotation:

```
@Transient
private String password;
```

If you simply don't want to show this field when you convert the object to a particular JSON representation, then this is a data representation problem, not a ORM mapping problem. You should skip this field when you convert your object to JSON. The implementation depends on what JSON converter you are using. For instance, if you use Jackson, then the `@JsonIgnore` annotation is what you need.

Comment: Sorry I think `@Transient` isn't what I want. What I want is I can get password when I select User table and when I select Project table, it won't give me the password. However, `@Transient`  will ignore password when I select User table.

Comment: This is not possible, because queries to two different entities (User and Project) inside a single persistence context would result in two different User objects representing a single row in the database, which violates the ORM principle of identity. You should really consider solving this problem on your presentation level.