# How to exclude fields from being fetched from db using Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am working with very complex Hibernate Criteria to fetch data from my db.

Suppose I have the following entities A, B, C, D(actually I have lot more such entities) and let their classes be

```
A{
    /*some other fields*/
    private String key;
    private List<B> bList;
}

B{
    /*Some other fields*/

    private Set<C> cSet;
}

C{
    /*Some other fields*/
    private D d;
}

D{
    /*Some fields*/
}
```

And let the criteria I use to fetch A be

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("key", "myKey"));

criteria.setFetchMode("bList", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setFetchMode("bList.cSet", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setFetchMode("bList.cSet.d", FetchMode.JOIN);

criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

A a = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

This works fine and I get the result. But as I already mentioned, this is a very simplified version of my actual query. My actual query has a lot of such join fetches and it causes performance issues. I cannot avoid this JOIN fetch mode as these fields are needed by the application immediately. I checked the query being fired to the db. A lot of fields of all A, B, C and D are being fetched from the db which are not needed. I am trying to prevent the fetching of these fields. I tried `Example.excludeProperty()` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970226/excluding-a-beans-field-in-hibernate-criteria-result/25970469#25970469). I doesn't shortens the query. When I use projections I am being forced to write a custom result transformer. Is there any simple solution for this problem? I am using PostgreSQL.

Thank you..

Comment: Using Criteria for complex queries (especially with multiple joins) will cause performance issues and I doubt you can do much to improve it. You should probably use Hibernate native queries as explained here https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

Comment: @dsp_user thank you for the sql query reference. I tried it. But as mentioned in the question, I have lot of joined collections(actually I have 4 collection joinings nested). I am getting an empty collection from the second level of joining onwards. Also I get a lot of copies of the A entity than expected(As much as the rows returned from the database). I am using SQLQuery.addEntity(String, Class) and SQLQuery.addJoin(String, String) in new query.

Answer (score 0):

excludeProperty should be applied in this way ---

```
Example example = Example.create(A).excludeProperty("property1")
                 .excludeProperty("property2");
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(A.class)
                     .add(example);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("key", "myKey"));

criteria.setFetchMode("bList", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setFetchMode("bList.cSet", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.setFetchMode("bList.cSet.d", FetchMode.JOIN);

criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

A a = criteria.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of  the variable `example`.

Comment: thanks for your effort. But this is exactly what I tried with `Example` and it doesn't seem to reduce the query fired to the db.